# Excel VBA - Search through list and pop-up message

Tags: excel, vba, search, compare, match

I would like to ask for some help regarding the following problem:
I have a workbook with two sheets. Sheet 2 contains 2 lists with phrases in them and Sheet 1 has some data. I want to create a macro that checks the data in Sheet 1 and if it finds a phrase that does not appear in the lists in Sheet 2 it gives a pop-up message. Furthermore,  Sheet 1 will contain phrases separated by commas. Is it possible to also check that as well? (see screenshot)
Although really simple, I have worked out the following, however, I am sure the answer is more complicated. 
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

[image: Sheet 1 with data]

[image: Sheet 2 with lists of phrases]

My code:

```
Sub check()
For i = 2 To 2

If Cells(i, "A") <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "B") Then
MsgBox "Phrase 1 does not match"
    End If

For j = 2 To 2
    If Cells(j, "B") <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, "C") Then
    MsgBox "Phrase 2 does not match"

End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you create a loop to "loop" through only one cell? (2 to 2)

Comment: @vacip Probably just to provide a small example of what the op is trying to do?  In any case you'd be better using `InStr` to locate the text since you're trying to find data within a cell rather than a complete match on value

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code should look like this

```
For all cells in column 'Phase 1'
 Use the SPLIT() function to split the comma separated values 
 and store them into a list of distinct values

  For all distinct values in the list
     Use the VLOOKUP function on the 'Phrase list 1' column in sheet2, 
     searching for the current value

     If vlookup returns a valid result then
         do nothing
     else
        pop up message
     end if

   end loop of distinct values

end loop of cells in column 'Phase 1'
```